# R: subset a data table by matching of strings

Tags: r, database, data.table, subset

I have this data table in R (47541025 rows):

```
require(data.table)
DT<-fread("pmiDistances.csv")

head(DT)

     language 1                        language 2            distance
1: Kho.CENTRAL_KHOISAN.GWI           Kho.CENTRAL_KHOISAN.GWI 0.0000000
2: Kho.CENTRAL_KHOISAN.GWI         Kho.CENTRAL_KHOISAN.GXANA 0.2195843
3: Kho.CENTRAL_KHOISAN.GWI Kho.CENTRAL_KHOISAN.KHOEKHOEGOWAB 0.6749363
4: Kho.CENTRAL_KHOISAN.GWI          Kho.CENTRAL_KHOISAN.KHWE 0.6089206
5: Kho.CENTRAL_KHOISAN.GWI        Kho.CENTRAL_KHOISAN.KORANA 0.7163111
6: Kho.CENTRAL_KHOISAN.GWI         Kho.CENTRAL_KHOISAN.KWADI 0.8017179
```

So this is basically a list of couple of nodes of a graph  and their distance

I'm interested in extracting a subset with the reciprocal distances of 41 languages, that I have saved in a .txt file

What is the smartest way to do this? (I don't think that 2 nested for loops will work)

Comment: What do you mean with reciprocal distance and can you show a few lines of the .txt file, please?

Comment: My bad, just the distance between the two languages! The .txt file is just a 1-column list of the languages I'm interested in

Comment: `DT[language1 %in% fortyOneLanguages & language2 %in% fortyOneLanguages ,]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@digEmAll demonstrates the typical way to do this:

```
DT[language1 %in% desired_subset & language2 %in% desired_subset]
```

You may also want to key your `data.table` since it's so huge, if you're planning on repeating this operation at all:

```
setkey(DT, language1, language2)

DT[.(desired_subset, desired_subset)]
```

It seems you would do well to read the [Getting Started Page](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started), most particularly for your question the [vignette on subsetting](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-keys-fast-subset.html).